# Re-initialiaze tabs in tabbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I've got a tab bar set up in a storyboard with 4 tabs. The app has a login system, and when I log out I want to zero-out the second and third tabs. The second and third tabs content depends upon which user is logged in, so I don't want the old info appearing there.

How would I re-initialise them?

Answer (score 5):

This is a situation suitable for `NSNotification` usage. When the 'logged-in' status changes, post a notification. Observe this notification in the appropriate view controllers and have then react by enabling / disabling / showing / clearing UI elements in their view.

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController;
NSMutableArray *tabBarButtons = [tabBarController.tabBar.items mutableCopy];
[tabBarButtons removeObjectAtIndex:1];
[tabBarButtons removeObjectAtIndex:2];
[tabBarController.tabBar setItems:tabBarButtons animated:NO];
```

Comment: I tried this in the App delegate and in TabBarController subclasss.. I get this error: 'Directly modifying a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not allowed'

Comment: @cannyboy have you tried replacing viewController instead of removing like in my solution?

Answer (score 3):

One way you can try using key value observing like this :-
Whenver you click on the logout store some value in string which is `NSString *selectedValue` make the `property` and `synthesize` of the same. So whenever string value will change below observer will be notified

// Also add below in your view controller.

```
[yourBtn addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentViewController.selectedValue" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:(__bridge void *)(self)];

-(void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
   if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"contentViewController.selectedValue"])
//your Code stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With :

```
NSMutableArray *tabBarButtons = [tabBar.items mutableCopy];
```

you will have a mutable copy of the array representing your tabs. So with this copy, you can change your tabs properties, remove tabs if you want, add others,...

And to finish, perform a

```
[tabBar setItems:tabBarButtons animated:/*YES or NO*/];
```

to apply your changes to your tab bar

Answer (score 2):

So basically you want to disable the tow tabs. 
You can use delegate method of "UITabbarController" ,

```
   - (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

And return NO, for which tab you want to make disable.

Comment: I don't want to disable, I want to reset the contents

Answer (score 2):

You can subclass your UITabViewController so it can listen to a NSNotification then in your UITabViewController why don't you create two new controllers to replace the old ones as below

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:_tabBarController.viewControllers];
SecondViewController * resetSecondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
ThirdViewController * resetThirdViewController = [[ThirdViewController alloc] init];
[viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:2 withObject:resetSecondViewController];
[viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:3 withObject:resetThirdViewController];
[_tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:NO];
```

Comment: By the way, another solution is to have UINavigationViewController as items of your UITabBarViewController and reinit the rootViewController of the second and third navigationController.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really use storyboards but in straight code this is a piece of cake.

In your AppDelegate.h create a property for tab 2 / tab 3 with the relevant view controllers.

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) MyViewController *tab2
@property (nonatomic,strong) MyOtherViewController *tab3
```

etc and use this to initialise the tabs - it will be delegate.tab2 or self.tab2 if you are in AppDelegate.m but globally accessible.

Off the top of my head you would initialise it like:

```
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:@[tab1,self.tab2,self.tab3,tab4]];
[self.window setRootViewController:self.tabBarController];
```

Now, when the user logs out run an app delegate method that either resets the view controller or puts something in its place.

e.g. in AppDelegate.m

```
-(void)logout
{
    [self clearView];
    // the rest of hte method
}

-(void)clearView
{
    [self.tab2 resetData];
}
```

in MyViewController.m

```
-(void)resetData
{
    [textFieldOrWhateverTheUIElementIs setText:@""];
// and so on
}
```

Simple.

Answer (score 0):

I have got 2 options

1. As you said tab 2 & 3 are showing based on user login. So for sure you will have userId of that user and you will be saving it some where like NSUserDefault. When you log out clear the userId and in 2 & 3 tabs load information if userId have some value.
2. Clear UserId and make or force user to login in a soft way be using this

   [method]      [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

on logout button action